# Pandas: help on how to concatenate more than 2 tables on a 3 keys

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have these three tables that I want to concatenate on three common keys (Date, Hour and trunk) to get this result:
[tables merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvrgs.png)

What is the simplest way to do it with pandas? I did some eperiments by creating a common key (concatenating Date+Hour+trunk) and simulating an OUTER JOIN between the first two tables and starting from the first one with pd.merge. But it has not been a satisfying experiment.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately pd.merge can maximum work on two dataframes. I need to join more than two tables

Comment: chain them together. `df1.merge(df2, ... ).merge(df3, ...)`